# No rule to make target src/core/librookery_core.a needed by src/exe/rookery_exe

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am still scraping the rust off of my c++ after many years of not doing this.

Here is my directory structure.

src
src/core
src/exe

This is so my unit tests don't have to fight with another main function which I've defined in src/exe.

Each of these directories has a CMakeLists.txt. (I'm building all of this using CLion.)

This is the one in src

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(${PROJECT_NAME}_src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(core)

add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(exe)
```

The one in src/core

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(rookery_core)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

and then the one in exe

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(rookery_exe)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_exe ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core)
```

and when I run it I get

```
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/rookery_core.dir/WorkFile.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX static library librookery_core.a
[ 40%] Built target rookery_core
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/exe/CMakeFiles/rookery_exe.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/core/librookery_core.a', needed by 'src/exe/rookery_exe'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:229: src/exe/CMakeFiles/rookery_exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

and it just built librookery_core library. Don't know what to do next.

Thanks.

Since asked for, here is the root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(rookery)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tst)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
```

Comment: It smells like there is something **above** `src/CMakeLists.txt`: The variable `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` is expanded into the top-level project name, but none of your `CMakeLists.txt` has `project(rookery)`, so your library name - `rookery_core` - would be expanded from `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core`.

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised this even configures correctly: There's no target `_src_exe` `target_link_libraries` could link libraries to... Also what do you expect `set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})` to do? Furthermore why are you setting the c++ standard seperately on each cmake file? The variable set in the toplevel dir is visible in subdirectories as well. You may want to apply this to the target themselves though: `set_target_properties(someTarget PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)`

Comment: @Tsyvarev, added requested cmake file.